# Pass-Through Stream (not having to save to memory in the middle)

Tags: c#, memory, stream, streamreader

In my c# program, I am working with an object (third-party, so I have no way of changing its source code) that takes a stream in in its constructor (`var myObject = new MyObject(stream);`).

My challenge is that I need to make some changes to some of the lines of my file prior to it being ready to be given to this object.

To do this, I wrote the following code (which does work):

```
using (var st = new MemoryStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(st))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var currentLine = reader.ReadLine().Replace(@"XXXX", @"YYYY");
            writer.Write(currentLine);
        }
        writer.Flush();
        st.Position = 0;
        var myObject = new MyObject(st);
    }
}
```

So, this does work, but it seems so inefficient since it is no longer really streaming the information, but storing it all in the memory stream before giving it through to the object.

Is there a way to create a transform / "pass-through stream" that will:

1. Read in each small amount from the streamreader
2. Make the adjustment on that small amount
3. Stream that amount through

So there won't be a large bit of memory storage in the middle?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create your own class that derives from Stream, and implements the required methods that your MyObject needs.

Implement all your Read/ReadAsync methods by calling the matching Read/ReadAsync methods on your StreamReader.  You can then modify the data as it passes through.

You'd have a bit of work to do if the modification requires some sort of understanding of the data as you'll be working in unknown quantities of bytes at a time. You would need to buffer the data to an extent required to do your necessary transformations, but how you do that is very specific to the transformation of the stream that you want to achieve.

Unfortunately the design of the C# Stream class is loaded down with lots of baggage, so implementing the entire API of Stream is quite a bit of work, but chances are your MyObject only calls one or two methods on Stream so a bit of experimentation should soon get it working.

Comment: Thank you! - That's what I'm trying to do now... I was just hoping there was a nicer / more simplistic way.... :/